# Comment not respecting line breaks (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, entities, comments

All of my comments for all of my content types do not respect show line breaks.  I have tried to dig pretty deep into this issue but I now feel quite stuck.

This is what I discovered.

- The problem is not related to the text formats. (I have verified that *Convert line breaks into HTML* is checked.)
- The problem may have to do with *safe_value*. I used `dsm()` to show content of the `$vars` variable inside the `hook_preprocess_field()` implementation of the theme, which shows the value of the comment body has line breaks, but *save_value* doesn't.
- The issue is not related to the format. With `dsm()` I have verified that the comment body is using  the *Filtered HTML* input format, which I believe is correct.

This is what `dsm()` outputs for the comment body.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I found this problem it was because the results of the filter were being stripped by another filter.

Go to **/admin/config/content/formats** and check your filter processing order. The 'Convert line breaks into HTML' should be the last one.

Comment: That was a good guess (Correct faulty and chopped off HTML) was last in the order but I changed it so that 'Convert line breaks into HTML' was last, and it is still happening.  I tried to clear the cache just to be safe but that didn't help.

Comment: @Mike2012 - Then one of your filters is stripping the line breaks themselves. Eliminate them one by one and find which one. Good luck.

Comment: ah, sweet thank you.  In my case it seemed that 'Limit allowed HTML tags' was the culprit.

Comment: Your welcome. Happy to have helped.

Comment: Just a quick follow up. Make sure that 'Limit allowed HTML tags' permits p and br, and put it after the 'Convert line breaks into HTML'. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and I solved it by visiting `/admin/structure/types/manage/<content-type>/{fields,comment}/display` and changing the format to *Default*. Then, I played with the input formats accordingly.